# Are there any plans for a new series of Quantum Leap?

Tags: quantum-leap

I think that Quantum Leap is one of the best TV series ever.

**My question is, will there be a remake/reboot? Will we get to see the effects that Sam's leaping had on his life *prior to the first leap***

Comment: Also, there's a similar [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/who-was-leaping-sam-beckett-in-time-was-it-god?rq=1) here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0ScMs6_I8s

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20060709102508/http://www.scifi.com/scifiwire/art-sfc.html?2002-07/09/12.30.sfc - Officially dead

Comment: http://www.tvguide.com/news/comic-quantum-leaping-1020879/ - Development hell.

Comment: The primary question has a yes/no answer, this is *hardly* opinion based. Voting to leave open.

Comment: Oh boy .........

Answer (score 3):

A new Quantum Leap series is indeed in production, and has been airing since September 2022. From [imdb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt17043230/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0_tt_8_nm_0_q_quantum%2520lea):

> Set 30 years after Dr. Sam Beckett stepped into the Quantum Leap accelerator and vanished, follows a new team that must restart the project hoping to understand the mysteries behind the machine and its creator.

Scott Bakula is not involved with the new series, however Susan Diol reprises her role as Beth Calavicci, Al's wife from the original series. The character of Janis Calavicci is also introduced as Al's daughter from the original series.

The character of Herbert "Magic" Williams also appears from the original series episode "[*The Leap Home (Part 2)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0681182/)" as a main character, albeit played by a new actor ([Ernie Hudson](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001368/)).

The series was [renewed for a second season](https://variety.com/2022/tv/news/quantum-leap-renewed-season-2-nbc-1235458610/amp/) in December 2022.

Answer (score 1):

**Kinda yes, probably no.**

Since the show was originally cancelled there have been two concerted efforts to revive it, once in 2002 by the then SCI FI channel (before they [stopped making science fiction shows](http://www.blastr.com/2009-3-20/sci-fi-president-dave-howe-answers-your-syfy-questions)) and again more recently with the show mooted as a possible TV film in 2010 by Scott Bakula;

> SCI FI will develop a two-hour movie based on the TV series Quantum
> Leap, which will also serve as a back-door pilot for a possible
> series. Series creator Don P. Bellisario will executive produce.
>
> <sub><sup>[New Leap, Tremors On SCI FI (2002)](https://web.archive.org/web/20060709162328/http://www.scifi.com/scifiwire/art-sfc.html?2002-07/09/12.30.sfc)</sup></sub>

and

> ...at Comic-Con on July 22, series star Scott Bakula revealed that a
> feature-film version of the classic 1989-1993 drama was in the works.
>
> "Everybody talks about doing a movie," he told the cheering capacity
> crowd packed in to one of the San Diego convention center's main
> rooms, adding that Leap's creator and exec producer Donald Bellisario
> was "working on a script for the film." **When pressed for details,
> Bakula—who also informed the crowd that his TNT drama Men of a Certain
> Age was about to begin filming its second season—said it was too soon
> to discuss a plot, but that it was "likely" he and costar Dean
> Stockwell would make appearances.**
>
> **"This is what I'm known for, and it's a great show to be known for,"
> Bakula affectionately admitted of his four seasons as time-jumping Dr.
> Sam Beckett. "It's a great piece of TV history."**
>
> <sub><sup>[Comic-Con: Is Quantum Leaping to the Megaplex?](http://www.tvguide.com/news/comic-quantum-leaping-1020879/)</sup></sub>

For the record, both ideas (a new series or a film pilot) are buried deep in [development hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_hell) with zero indication that either will ever get made.

Comment: Watch nerd HQ Scott and Don p say they are always thinking about a remake/ Movie has to be in next ten years ...

Comment: @ShaunWright - Yeah, it's become something of an in-joke where they're concerned. If they were actually interested in it, they'd have found someone to fund it a decade ago.